# Contacts full/free text search

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully implemented a field search with the use of the $filter parameter as I understood the odata documentation correctly the $search parameter can be used to perform a free text search but the documenation mention something like the service decides what makes an entity complaint with the search critera but I can't find any information about which fields are checked on contact $search. Is it possible to perform a search on the entire contact object or is there some information about the search support for contacts

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching personal contacts (like ../v1.0/me/contacts) or org contacts (../beta/contacts)? I don't think either of these support $search. **However**, if it's personal contacts, or people you communicate with that you want to search, you should check out the new People API: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/social_overview.  This does support $search.  Not sure if this will work for you...

Comment: The people api looks great and I think that one is what I need. But the search works but if I want to searh on a specific property $search="givenName:Mike" it returns no results where $search=mike gives the result I expect. The contact returned by free/full search has the following "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "Directory"
                }
            ],